# Sync Data in Core Data

Tags: swift, core-data

I have this array named students_server and students_db.
students_server get the array of students from the server and students_db get the array of students from the core data.
I want to sync the students_server in the core data

1) Delete the students which aren't present in the students_server

2) Update the students which are there in the core data and students_server

3) Insert the students which are not there in the core data but there in the students_server

Take the following schema for the solution

```
class Students: NSManagedObject {
@NSManaged var id: String
@NSManaged var image: String
@NSManaged var name: String }
```

Like in Android we have this

`CREATE TABLE mytable (
  id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  name TEXT NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE (id) ON CONFLICT REPLACE
)`

Comment: Right now am doing it this way https://gist.github.com/anirudhamahale/d4c4c62e46e7dcdb9d13dbbb7ac7e6e9

Comment: Your Android approach looks like it's SQLite. You could use SQLite directly on iOS if you want.

Comment: Ya, that's a good suggestion but am finding how I can do it using SQLite wrapper i.e. Core Data framework.

Comment: Core Data is not a SQLite wrapper. It uses SQLIte but its API is very different. Trying to use Core Data like SQLite is a good way to do Core Data poorly.